# Opencart different seo urls opening same page

Tags: php, opencart

How can you customize seo  urls in OpenCart? For example http://example.com/category1/category2 is showing category2 page it is no problem but http://example.com/category1/category2/category3 is showing category2 same page what is problem ?

I know OpenCart provides SEO URLs for products, categories, manufacturers and information pages, but it doesn't look like there is anything built-in (at least prior to version 1.5.0) for anything else.

Comment: sorry for bad english it is about stackoverflow rules. my problem is on first paragraph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happened when duplicate  alias

Fix it:

Search on database on table "url_alias"

you will find 2 keyword with same value change of of them

Comment: i found it before your answer but yes it is true thanks :)